# Highcharts Stacklabel Style backgroundColor

Tags: highcharts

How can I change background color of a stacklabel. I didn't find any example to this.

I tried ... but it dont worked.

```
yAxis: {
            title: {text:'%'},
            stackLabels: {                  
                    style: {
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',    
                    color: 'black',
                    borderWidth: 1
                },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable [`useHTML`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels.useHTML).

```
    stackLabels: {
        style: {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',    
            color: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        enabled: true,
        useHTML: true
    }
```

Comment: so easy! but in my case is better set as false. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With **formatter** and enable **useHTML**

`

```
     yAxis:{  stackLabels: {
            style: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            enabled: true,
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                 return '<span style="background-color:red">' + this.total + '</span>';
            }
        }
    },`
```